# Crm 2011. How get Current user in mvc application

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a custom mvc application, what i want to use as a part of crm 2011
(for example i have a button at crm panel, which call action at my mvc application)

Can I get user credentials, which log in in crm and press button?

I use this code to run organization service. But WhoAmIRequest return system or null (depend of impersonate property in web.config)

```
var organizationUri = new Uri(Configuration.OrganizationUri());
var credentials = new ClientCredentials();

credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = (DefaultCredentials != null) ? DefaultCredentials : CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

IServiceConfiguration<IOrganizationService> orgConfigInfo = ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateConfiguration<IOrganizationService>(organizationUri);

var service = new OrganizationServiceProxy(orgConfigInfo, credentials);

WhoAmIResponse response = (WhoAmIResponse)service.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest());
service.CallerId = response.UserId;
```

Comment: Can you add an example of how you are calling your MVC Application? I would imagine you could pass in the Id of the current user from CRM

Comment: For example, http://host/ISV/ApplicationWeb/CustomController.mvc/CustomAction?userGuid=123&param2=123. And 'yes', i put userguid at the link. But, i think, it's bad, because user can change guid at the browser. I try to find better way, how do it in code

Answer (score 0):

You could read the current Username

`User.Identity.Name`

and compare it with the domainname in MS CRM.